# IIS 7.5: How to let him serve by default all file extensions (without manually adding them)?

Tags: iis, iis-7, webserver, file-extension

It is a little annoying that every time when you put a "new" file-extension on your IIS 7.5 backed server for simple http-download you have to think about adding the extension to the IIS configuration!

> (e.g. provide a file zipped in the format .7z)

Is there a way to tell IIS "serve anything" (like it is the default setting in Apache-Webserver) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You should add the following to the MIME types:

```
extension:  .*
MIME type:  application/octet-stream
```

After that (depending on the browser) every unknown file will be forced to download.

Comment: If  your file has NO extension, then use `.` to match it instead of `.*`

Comment: @CarlosRendon Maybe add an alternative answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 9):

You should add the following to the MIME types:

For files with any extension (i.e. foo.somethingcrazyhere)

`extension:  .*
MIME type:  application/octet-stream`

For files ***without*** any extension (i.e. SOMETHING_CRAZY_HERE_NO_DOT)

`extension:  .
MIME type:  application/octet-stream`

Answer (score -2):

Try the following in your web.config. This basically tells IIS to ignore the extension whitelist.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It says here (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions#005) that the default value is true, so I don't see how this changes anything.

Comment: I wrote this when I was working for a financial firm - they had a machine.config deployed on their web-server VM template that set this to false, so I didn't realise this.

Comment: This solution does not work... I am trying currently serve .rdf